# Need help creating a txt file in a folder which, is in the same directory

Tags: python, file, text, directory

I'm pretty new to python. I have a homwork problem where we need to analyze corpora and then compare them. We also have to save the files as a .txt file after is has been processed with an attribute, the size.

So I need to create a .txt file in a seperate folder called trigram-models. 
This folder is in the same directory as my python file. I think i have to use the os module but i'm not sure how.

Here is my code:

```
from langdetect import read_trigrams, trigram_table, write_trigrams
import os

def make_profiles(datafolder, profilefolder, size):    

    filelist = []
    for file in os.listdir('./training'):
        filelist.append(file)
    print(filelist)

    for file in filelist:           
        filen = "./training/"+file
        print("fi", filen)

        maketable = trigram_table(filen, size)

        readdata = read_trigrams(filen)
        #print("re", readdata)

        splitname = str(file).split('-')
        newname = splitname[0] + "." + str(size) + '.txt'

        endtable = write_trigrams(readdata, newname)

    return (endtable)

make_profiles("./training", "./trigram-models", 20)
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific as for what's the problem you're facing? Does this code crash? Does it work fine but doesn't produce the result you want?

Comment: Right now when i run the code, all the text files are saved in the same directory as where the python file is saved. But i need the text files to be saved in a folder in that directory. Sorry for the lack of info

Answer (score 0):

To create a directory, I would use the following format which relies on a try / catch and prevents an error if the directory already exists:

```
dirName = 'tempDir'

try:
    # Create target Directory
    os.mkdir(dirName)
    print("Directory " , dirName ,  " Created ") 
except FileExistsError:
    print("Directory " , dirName ,  " already exists")
```

To change your directory you can use the following:

```
os.chdir(directoryLocation)
```

I recommend reading [chapter 8 in automating the boring stuff with python](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter8/).

I hope this helps. If you have any questions please don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, be sure to indent all the code in your method for it to be appropriately enclosed.

You are also passing relative paths (*datafolder, profilefolder*) for your folders as method arguments, so you should use them inside the method instead.

Lastly, to create a file in a folder, I would recommend using the following algorithm:

```py
file_path = '/'.join(profilefolder, newname)

with open(file_path, 'w') as ouf:
    ouf.write(endtable)
```

You will probably need to replace "endtable" with a string representation of your data.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not using the argument `profileFolder`, where you specify the name of the output directory. So first of all you should use this information for creating a folder before processing your files.

So first thing would be to create this output directory.
Second is to save your files there, and to do that you need to append the file name to the output directory. Something like this:

```
def make_profiles(data_folder, output_folder, size):    

    filelist = []
    for file in os.listdir(data_folder):
        filelist.append(file)

    # Create output folder
    if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
        os.mkdir(output_folder)

    for file in filelist:           
        filen = "./training/"+file
        #print("fi", filen)

        splitname = str(file).split('-')

        # Create new file by appending name to output_folder
        newname = os.path.join(output_folder, splitname[0] + "." + str(size) + '.txt')


    return (endtable)

make_profiles(./training, './trigram-models', 20)
```

Note that you can also specify the relative folder name (i.e. "trigram-models" only) and then create the output directory by appending this name to the current path:

```
output_folder = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), output_folder)
```

Also (not related to the question) this piece of code could be optimized:

```
filelist = []
for file in os.listdir(data_folder):
    filelist.append(file)
```

`os.listdir` already returns a list, so you could directly write:

```
filelist = os.listdir(data_folder)
```

But since you're interested in the absolute path of each file you could better do:

```
filelist = [os.path.abspath(f) for f in os.listdir(data_folder)]
```

where you basically take each file returned by `os.listdir` and you append its absolute path to your file list. Doing this you could avoid the line `filen = "./training/"+file`.

So in the end your code should look something like this:

```
def make_profiles(data_folder, output_folder, size):    

    filelist = [os.abspath(f) for f in os.listdir(data_folder)]

    # Create output folder
    if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
        os.mkdir(output_folder)

    for file in filelist:           
        splitname = str(file).split('-')

        # [...add other pieces of code]

        # Create new file by appending name to output_folder
        newname = os.path.join(output_folder, splitname[0] + "." + str(size) + '.txt')

        # [...add other pieces of code]
    return (endtable)

make_profiles(./training, './trigram-models', 20)
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast and detailed answer! But when i try to run the program now, i get an error: " AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'abspath' ". I have imported the modules os and os.path. But still i get this error. Do you have any idea why this happens and how i can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

As to clarify on toti08's answer, you should replace os.absdir with os.path.absdir.

```py
filelist = [os.path.abspath(f) for f in os.listdir(data_folder)]
```

instead of

```py
filelist = [os.abspath(f) for f in os.listdir(data_folder)]
```